# Can a webservice upload an image to any types of server?

Tags: web-services, java-me

I want to upload images from a phone device into a computer web-server using java-me and webservice. The computer web-server is any kind of hardware and operating systems. So I want to know if a webservice can create a directory in the server and upload the image into it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes you can perform it as file upload.
check this wiki article, [HTTP Post multipart file upload in Java ME.](http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/HTTP_Post_multipart_file_upload_in_Java_ME)